# How to pass Parameter to Snowflake procedure using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a snowflake procedure but I am getting an "invalid identified A"

following is the statement:

```
create or replace procedure sp_procedureName (A date, B string)
return string Null
language Javascript 
EXECUTE As Caller
AS
$$
with cte as (Select column1, column2 from table1 where colA >= A and colB = B),
cte1 as (Select column1, column2 from table2 where colA >= A and colB = B)
Select column1, column2, column1, column2 from cte1, cte2  //Example select statement
```

so when I am passing those paramteres my procedure is failing with "invalid identified error"

can someone help me to get the correct way to pass those parameter values to procedure

Comment: You cannot run a SQL statement in a Javascript stored procedure that way. SQL statements must be called through the Stored Procedure API referenced in the `snowflake` object:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html

Comment: @GregPavlik is there any solution where we can use SQL in stored procedure language?

Comment: Yes. You can currently write stored procedures in either JavaScript or SQL Script. Other languages (Python, Java) are in development or preview. Here's documeentation on SQL Script: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get started. You can reference the Snowflake Stored Procedure API: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html

Note that the date must be passed using the `.toISOString()` function because Javascript stringifies Date types into a string that Snowflake does not like. Snowflake is okay with the ISO string version.

```
create or replace procedure sp_procedureName (A date, B string)
returns string
language javascript 
execute As caller
AS
$$

var sql = `with cte as (Select column1, column2 from table1 where colA >= :1 and colB = :2),
cte1 as (Select column1, column2 from table2 where colA >= :1 and colB = :2)
Select column1, column2, column1, column2 from cte1, cte2  //Example select statement`;

var rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql, binds:[A.toISOString(), B]});

while (rs.next()){

    // Do something for each row here.

}

$$;

call sp_procedureName('2020-01-01', 'Hello world');
```